# Should I render optional sections of a form via partials?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

As an exercise in learning .NET, I'm moving some simple forms over into MVC, and have run into an issue. The form in question is a multi-part form that has option sections. For example, Section 0 is static and contains information like username, real name, email address. After that is a radio button with several options. If you click the first radio, it displays Section 1. If you choose the second, it displays Section 2, and so on.

In WebForms this was no biggy, as I just validated on postback and said if Radio1.Selected validate this, if Radio2.Selected validate that, etc. So now I've got a strongly-typed view with [Required] members, which obviously isn't going to work - I can't require members that aren't always going to be required.

With that said, is this the correct approach to the problem:

- Create the members that belong in Section 0 in my strongly-typed view model class.
- Create references to each partial's strongly-typed class in my view model class.
- Create the partial views and then render them in the main view.
- Depending on which radio button is selected, render the appropriate partial view.
- Validate the model like usual...which hopefully will cascade to the partial models.

Does this make sense, or is the approach wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That's a typical scenario where you need conditional validation, i.e. if some value is set then validate that some other value is required. Achieving this with static data annotations which are simple attributes baked at compile time can quickly turn into a nightmare due to their declarative nature. Well, you could always roll your own custom validation attributes but the problem with attributes is that you will have to specify property names as strings as they need to be known at compile time.

That's one of the reasons why I use [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/). Not only that validation rules are separate from the view models and that it [integrates really nicely with ASP.NET MVC](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation) but handling scenarios like this would be very easy. You could have a sub-view model containing all the properties of the sub-section and then conditionally include it based on the value of a given property on the main view model inside its validator.

Comment: "but the problem with attributes is that you will have to specify property names as strings as they need to be known at compile time."  This isn't true.  You can always cast and go from there.